# Dynamic Nav Query Designer

Tags: nav

I am new with Dynamics NAV Query Designer . 
Could any body help me how i can Translate this in Query Object in Dynamic Nav 2013

```
Select ProductNo , ParentProductNo 
from  Producttable 

Where  ProductNo  = ParentProductNo 


 AND ProductNo in 
             (  Select ProductNo from Sales
                 Where SalesType =BB
             )

And ParentProductNo  not in 
    (  Select ParentProductNo  where ProductType = 'Indoor' )
```

Answer (score 0):

NAV query is a simple object, it never intended to reveal the full force of SQL to C/AL, and it does not support subqueries.
But you can rewrite your query to use joins instead of nested selects.

It should look like this:

```
select p1.ProductNo, p1.ParentProductNo from 
  Producttable p1 join Sales s on p1.ProductNo = s.ProductNo and s.SalesType = 'BB'
    left outer join Producttable p2 on p1.ParentProductNo = p2.ParentProductNo and p2.ProductType = 'Indoor'
where p2.ParentProductNo is null and p1.ProductNo = p1.ParentProductNo
```

Table name in the last select statement is missing, but I assume it is "Producttable".

Now it is possible to a create a NAV query object with 3 dataitems. First inner join is linked via a simple data item link (just set the DataItemLink property).
For outer join, select DataItemLinkType = "SQL Advanced Options" and choose "Left Outer Join" as a join type ("SQLJoinType" property).